# AWS Datasync Include filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-datasync

I'm trying to transfer files using Datasync based on below regular expression. But I found on AWS page that include filter only contains simple_pattern. Is there any way I can achieve this? Please help!

Needed file filter regex(include filter):
[0-9]{8}(_ABC)[0-9]{8}.csv